# gitlab-runner status 500 internal server error

Tags: gitlab

I have been stuck for quite some time. 
I wanted to use Gitlab for some personal projects and I am running it on my own server.

I just recently took interest in the CI/CD part of Gitlab and wanted to try it out.
However the runner keeps looping with a 500 internal server error.

```
WARNING: Checking for jobs... failed                runner=YmfuCQdb 
status=500 Internal Server Error
Feeding runners to channel                          builds=0
Dialing: tcp git.server.be:443 ...
```

I have googled this issue and cannot for the life of me solve it.

Some background information:
I migrated this server a while back, everything functioned just fine.
Any information you need I will try to provide.

Edit: I found the following in my logs [sanitized]

```
Started POST "/api/v4/jobs/request" for 0.0.0.0 at 2019-10-03 19:32:06 +0000

Processing by Gitlab::RequestForgeryProtection::Controller#index as JSON

Parameters: {"info"=>{"name"=>"gitlab-runner", "version"=>"12.3.0", "revision"=>"a8a019e0", "platform"=>"windows", "architecture"=>"amd64", "executor"=>"shell", "shell"=>"powershell", "features"=>{"variables"=>"[FILTERED]", "image"=>false, "services"=>false, "artifacts"=>true, "cache"=>true, "shared"=>true, "upload_multiple_artifacts"=>true, "upload_raw_artifacts"=>true, "session"=>false, "terminal"=>false, "refspecs"=>true, "masking"=>true, "proxy"=>false}}, "token"=>"[FILTERED]", "request_forgery_protection"=>{"info"=>{"name"=>"gitlab-runner", "version"=>"12.3.0", "revision"=>"a8a019e0", "platform"=>"windows", "architecture"=>"amd64", "executor"=>"shell", "shell"=>"powershell", "features"=>{"variables"=>"[FILTERED]", "image"=>false, "services"=>false, "artifacts"=>true, "cache"=>true, "shared"=>true, "upload_multiple_artifacts"=>true, "upload_raw_artifacts"=>true, "session"=>false, "terminal"=>false, "refspecs"=>true, "masking"=>true, "proxy"=>false}}, "token"=>"[FILTERED]"}}

Can't verify CSRF token authenticity.

This CSRF token verification failure is handled internally by `GitLab::RequestForgeryProtection`

Unlike the logs may suggest, this does not result in an actual 422 response to the user

For API requests, the only effect is that `current_user` will be `nil` for the duration of the request

Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

OpenSSL::Cipher::CipherError ():

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/encryptor-3.0.0/lib/encryptor.rb:98:in `final'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/encryptor-3.0.0/lib/encryptor.rb:98:in `crypt'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/encryptor-3.0.0/lib/encryptor.rb:49:in `decrypt'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/gitlab/crypto_helper.rb:27:in `aes256_gcm_decrypt'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/app/models/concerns/token_authenticatable_strategies/encrypted.rb:45:in `get_token'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/app/models/concerns/token_authenticatable_strategies/base.rb:27:in `ensure_token'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/app/models/concerns/token_authenticatable_strategies/encrypted.rb:32:in `ensure_token'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/app/models/concerns/token_authenticatable.rb:40:in `block in add_authentication_token_field'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:426:in `block in make_lambda'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:198:in `block (2 levels) in halting'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:606:in `block (2 levels) in default_terminator'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:605:in `catch'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:605:in `block in default_terminator'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:199:in `block in halting'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:513:in `block in invoke_before'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:513:in `each'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:513:in `invoke_before'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:131:in `run_callbacks'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:816:in `_run_save_callbacks'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:342:in `create_or_update'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:275:in `save'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/validations.rb:46:in `save'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:310:in `block (2 levels) in save'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:387:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:265:in `transaction'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:212:in `transaction'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:385:in `with_transaction_returning_status'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:310:in `block in save'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:325:in `rollback_active_record_state!'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:309:in `save'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/suppressor.rb:44:in `save'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/state_machines-activerecord-0.5.1/lib/state_machines/integrations/active_record.rb:509:in `block in save'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/state_machines-activerecord-0.5.1/lib/state_machines/integrations/active_record.rb:528:in `block in around_save'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/state_machines-0.5.0/lib/state_machines/transition_collection.rb:150:in `block in run_actions'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/state_machines-0.5.0/lib/state_machines/transition_collection.rb:170:in `catch_exceptions'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/state_machines-0.5.0/lib/state_machines/transition_collection.rb:148:in `run_actions'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/state_machines-0.5.0/lib/state_machines/transition_collection.rb:133:in `run_callbacks'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/state_machines-0.5.0/lib/state_machines/transition_collection.rb:224:in `run_callbacks'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/state_machines-0.5.0/lib/state_machines/transition_collection.rb:128:in `block in run_callbacks'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/state_machines-0.5.0/lib/state_machines/transition.rb:371:in `before'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/state_machines-0.5.0/lib/state_machines/transition.rb:190:in `block in run_callbacks'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/state_machines-0.5.0/lib/state_machines/transition.rb:292:in `block in pausable'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/state_machines-0.5.0/lib/state_machines/transition.rb:292:in `catch'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/state_machines-0.5.0/lib/state_machines/transition.rb:292:in `pausable'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/state_machines-0.5.0/lib/state_machines/transition.rb:190:in `run_callbacks'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/state_machines-0.5.0/lib/state_machines/transition_collection.rb:127:in `run_callbacks'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/state_machines-0.5.0/lib/state_machines/transition_collection.rb:212:in `run_callbacks'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/state_machines-0.5.0/lib/state_machines/transition_collection.rb:63:in `block (2 levels) in perform'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/state_machines-0.5.0/lib/state_machines/transition_collection.rb:63:in `catch'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/state_machines-0.5.0/lib/state_machines/transition_collection.rb:63:in `block in perform'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/state_machines-0.5.0/lib/state_machines/transition_collection.rb:182:in `block in within_transaction'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/state_machines-0.5.0/lib/state_machines/transition.rb:171:in `block in within_transaction'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/state_machines-0.5.0/lib/state_machines/machine.rb:1868:in `block in within_transaction'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/state_machines-activerecord-0.5.1/lib/state_machines/integrations/active_record.rb:555:in `block in transaction'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:267:in `block in transaction'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:239:in `block in within_new_transaction'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/2.6.0/monitor.rb:230:in `mon_synchronize'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:236:in `within_new_transaction'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:267:in `transaction'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:212:in `transaction'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/state_machines-activerecord-0.5.1/lib/state_machines/integrations/active_record.rb:554:in `transaction'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/state_machines-0.5.0/lib/state_machines/machine.rb:1868:in `within_transaction'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/state_machines-0.5.0/lib/state_machines/transition.rb:170:in `within_transaction'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/state_machines-0.5.0/lib/state_machines/transition_collection.rb:181:in `within_transaction'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/state_machines-0.5.0/lib/state_machines/transition_collection.rb:62:in `perform'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/state_machines-activerecord-0.5.1/lib/state_machines/integrations/active_record.rb:528:in `around_save'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/state_machines-activerecord-0.5.1/lib/state_machines/integrations/active_record.rb:509:in `save'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/state_machines-0.5.0/lib/state_machines/transition_collection.rb:154:in `block (2 levels) in run_actions'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/state_machines-0.5.0/lib/state_machines/transition_collection.rb:154:in `each'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/state_machines-0.5.0/lib/state_machines/transition_collection.rb:154:in `block in run_actions'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/state_machines-0.5.0/lib/state_machines/transition_collection.rb:170:in `catch_exceptions'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/state_machines-0.5.0/lib/state_machines/transition_collection.rb:148:in `run_actions'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/state_machines-0.5.0/lib/state_machines/transition_collection.rb:60:in `perform'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/state_machines-0.5.0/lib/state_machines/transition.rb:163:in `perform'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/state_machines-0.5.0/lib/state_machines/event.rb:155:in `fire'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/state_machines-0.5.0/lib/state_machines/event.rb:219:in `block in add_actions'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/state_machines-0.5.0/lib/state_machines/machine.rb:729:in `block (2 levels) in define_helper'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/state_machines-0.5.0/lib/state_machines/event.rb:224:in `block in add_actions'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/state_machines-0.5.0/lib/state_machines/machine.rb:729:in `block (2 levels) in define_helper'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/app/services/ci/register_job_service.rb:95:in `assign_runner!'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/app/services/ci/register_job_service.rb:50:in `block in execute'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:71:in `each'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:71:in `each'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/app/services/ci/register_job_service.rb:44:in `execute'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/api/runner.rb:120:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Runner>'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/grape-1.1.0/lib/grape/endpoint.rb:57:in `call'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/grape-1.1.0/lib/grape/endpoint.rb:57:in `block (2 levels) in generate_api_method'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:170:in `instrument'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/grape-1.1.0/lib/grape/endpoint.rb:56:in `block in generate_api_method'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/grape-1.1.0/lib/grape/endpoint.rb:262:in `block in run'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:170:in `instrument'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/grape-1.1.0/lib/grape/endpoint.rb:243:in `run'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/grape-1.1.0/lib/grape/endpoint.rb:313:in `block in build_stack'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/grape-1.1.0/lib/grape/middleware/base.rb:31:in `call!'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/grape-1.1.0/lib/grape/middleware/base.rb:24:in `call'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/grape-1.1.0/lib/grape/middleware/base.rb:31:in `call!'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/grape-1.1.0/lib/grape/middleware/base.rb:24:in `call'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rack-oauth2-1.9.3/lib/rack/oauth2/server/resource.rb:20:in `_call'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rack-oauth2-1.9.3/lib/rack/oauth2/server/resource/bearer.rb:8:in `_call'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rack-oauth2-1.9.3/lib/rack/oauth2/server/abstract/handler.rb:17:in `call'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/grape-1.1.0/lib/grape/middleware/error.rb:38:in `block in call!'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/grape-1.1.0/lib/grape/middleware/error.rb:37:in `catch'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/grape-1.1.0/lib/grape/middleware/error.rb:37:in `call!'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/grape-1.1.0/lib/grape/middleware/base.rb:24:in `call'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/grape_logging-1.7.0/lib/grape_logging/middleware/request_logger.rb:60:in `block in call!'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/grape_logging-1.7.0/lib/grape_logging/middleware/request_logger.rb:58:in `catch'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/grape_logging-1.7.0/lib/grape_logging/middleware/request_logger.rb:58:in `call!'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/grape-1.1.0/lib/grape/middleware/base.rb:24:in `call'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/head.rb:12:in `call'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/grape-1.1.0/lib/grape/endpoint.rb:227:in `call!'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/grape-1.1.0/lib/grape/endpoint.rb:221:in `call'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/grape-1.1.0/lib/grape/router/route.rb:72:in `exec'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/grape-1.1.0/lib/grape/router.rb:121:in `process_route'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/grape-1.1.0/lib/grape/router.rb:74:in `block in identity'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/grape-1.1.0/lib/grape/router.rb:93:in `transaction'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/grape-1.1.0/lib/grape/router.rb:72:in `identity'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/grape-1.1.0/lib/grape/router.rb:57:in `block in call'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/grape-1.1.0/lib/grape/router.rb:137:in `with_optimization'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/grape-1.1.0/lib/grape/router.rb:56:in `call'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/grape-1.1.0/lib/grape/api.rb:119:in `call'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/grape-1.1.0/lib/grape/api.rb:45:in `call!'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/grape-1.1.0/lib/grape/api.rb:40:in `call'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:19:in `block in <class:Constraints>'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:48:in `serve'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:52:in `block in serve'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:35:in `each'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:35:in `serve'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:840:in `call'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/gitlab/middleware/rails_queue_duration.rb:27:in `call'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/gitlab/metrics/rack_middleware.rb:17:in `block in call'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/gitlab/metrics/transaction.rb:57:in `run'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/gitlab/metrics/rack_middleware.rb:17:in `call'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/gitlab/middleware/multipart.rb:103:in `call'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/gitlab/request_profiler/middleware.rb:16:in `call'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/gitlab/middleware/go.rb:20:in `call'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/gitlab/etag_caching/middleware.rb:13:in `call'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/gitlab/middleware/correlation_id.rb:16:in `block in call'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/gitlab-labkit-0.3.0/lib/labkit/correlation/correlation_id.rb:18:in `use_id'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/gitlab/middleware/correlation_id.rb:15:in `call'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/batch-loader-1.4.0/lib/batch_loader/middleware.rb:11:in `call'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/apollo_upload_server-2.0.0.beta.3/lib/apollo_upload_server/middleware.rb:20:in `call'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rack-attack-4.4.1/lib/rack/attack.rb:107:in `call'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/warden-1.2.7/lib/warden/manager.rb:36:in `block in call'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/warden-1.2.7/lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `catch'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/warden-1.2.7/lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `call'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rack-cors-1.0.2/lib/rack/cors.rb:97:in `call'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/tempfile_reaper.rb:15:in `call'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/etag.rb:25:in `call'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/conditional_get.rb:38:in `call'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/head.rb:12:in `call'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/http/content_security_policy.rb:18:in `call'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/gitlab/middleware/read_only/controller.rb:40:in `call'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/gitlab/middleware/read_only.rb:18:in `call'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:232:in `context'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:226:in `call'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:670:in `call'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:98:in `run_callbacks'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:26:in `call'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:61:in `call'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:33:in `call'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/gitlab/middleware/basic_health_check.rb:25:in `call'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `block in call'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:71:in `block in tagged'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:28:in `tagged'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:71:in `tagged'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:81:in `call'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/gitlab/request_context.rb:26:in `call'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/request_store-1.3.1/lib/request_store/middleware.rb:9:in `call'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:27:in `call'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/method_override.rb:22:in `call'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/gitlab/metrics/requests_rack_middleware.rb:29:in `call'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sentry-raven-2.9.0/lib/raven/integrations/rack.rb:51:in `call'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:524:in `call'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/railtie.rb:190:in `public_send'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/railtie.rb:190:in `method_missing'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/gitlab/middleware/release_env.rb:12:in `call'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:68:in `block in call'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:53:in `each'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:53:in `call'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/unicorn-5.4.1/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:606:in `process_client'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/unicorn-worker-killer-0.4.4/lib/unicorn/worker_killer.rb:52:in `process_client'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/unicorn-5.4.1/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:701:in `worker_loop'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/unicorn-5.4.1/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:549:in `spawn_missing_workers'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/unicorn-5.4.1/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:142:in `start'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/unicorn-5.4.1/bin/unicorn:126:in `<top (required)>'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/unicorn:23:in `load'

/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/unicorn:23:in `<main>'
```

Comment: are there any logs you can look at?

Comment: Not that I know

Comment: Ok, so apparantly there are logs, I will provide some more info soon.

Comment: @Moab after checking some resources it seems that which you see in the question is all the logging I'm going to get

Comment: Nevermind, logs are on gitlab server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that I skipped a step of migration, namely the part where you have to copy the secrets file.

The issue was that the original server where I migrated from had rained out of the cloud it was in and thus the files were lost.

However, gitlab has a procedure to fix this here: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/raketasks/backup_restore.html#when-the-secrets-file-is-lost